# Git (on Mac): finder shows files that should not be in branch

Tags: git

For this branch story note that terminal shows the exact same pathname when I do the `pwd` command.

I just learned how to branch with git (master branch tracked only a readme file). So I created another branch, and I untracked my readme file and created a new file which I called readme_dagboek (name of the branch). I was amazed that when I checked out from one branch to the other that the finder showed this as well.

So in the branch dagboek I dumped an old project that I need to adapt (only got access to 1 private repo). It is my idea that I never touch this branch again, I only need to copy/paste code from it.

The strange thing that happened is when I checked out to the master branch I saw 2 files of the dagboek branch still in my Finder. These are the "Classes" folder, and the "Dagboek(something).xcodeproj" (see first image). These files belong to the Dagboek branch, not to the master branch.

[image: Finder display of master branch]

The strange thing is, when I do the command `git ls-files`, it does not indicate the two files as being tracked.

So I deleted the files (`rm <filename>`), and they now do not show up anymore in the master branch, and still show up in the dagboek branch, which is what I want (see image 2), but I am still wondering, what's going on here? How come Finder displayed them in the first place when I was in the master branch? If I would've been busy in the dagboek branch at that moment, then all the files of image 2 should've been there as well, but they weren't.

[image: All kinds of files in the dagboek branch]

Answer (score 2):

Untracked files (ones that you have never `add`ed) do not exist in *any* branch. They are in your working copy, and switching branches will generally not affect them at all. This is also true of uncommitted changes.

If you wish to have files in one branch that do not exist in another you'll have to *commit them* to that branch.

For example:

```
# Create a new branch and check it out
git checkout -b dagboek

# Edit your new file
$EDITOR readme-dagboek.txt

# Commit this file to the branch
git add readme-dagboek.txt
git commit
```

Now switching branches back to `master` should not show `readme-dagboek.txt`.

This is by design. Imagine that you're working on something and you realize that it should actually be committed to a different branch. You wouldn't want switching to a different branch to remove your changes. Instead, you switch to the branch where you want to commit and commit.